# c# Merge service into one

Tags: c#, service

I have this service that will be call from a Web API and I want to see if there is a way to combine the two together using the model that is being passed in?

> Can I use something like getType to see the type of object?

```
    public ResultStatus InsertUsersDownload(UserLog userLog)
    {
        return Db.UsersDownload(userLog);
    }

    public ResultStatus InsertNonUsersDownload(NonUserLog nonUserLog)
    {
        return Db.NonUsersDownload(nonUserLog);
    }
```

Model

Comment: you can use reflection for this

Comment: Are there any similarities between the two objects passed? Also can you show the properties of the two objects?

Comment: I have included the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `is` operator to check the type. Then your method will look like this:

```
public ResultStatus InsertDownload(object log)
 {
 if(log is UserLog userLog)
  {
  return glDb.UsersDownload(userLog);
  }
 else if(log is NonUserLog nonUserLog)
  {
  return glDb.NonUsersDownload(nonUserLog);
  }
 else
  {
  throw new ArgumentException("invalid type", nameof(log));
  }
 }
```

If `UserLog` and `NonUserLog` share a common base class, you can also use that instead of `object`.

But you should really think whether this improves your code. If you have to check for a type and do different stuff depending of the type, this is often a sign of bad class design.

EDIT: I just saw your code of the model. They have the only difference that your `UserLog` class has an additional property `IsProfessional`. Maybe you could merge your classes into one by adding an additional property `IsUser`:

```
public class Log 
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Remote_Addr { get; set; }
    public string Local_Addr { get; set; }
    public string Http_User_Agent { get; set; }
    public string Http_Referer { get; set; }
    public bool? IsMobile { get; set; }
    public int? DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string AppType { get; set; }
    public bool? IsProfessional { get; set; }
    public bool IsUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could write your function that way:

```
public ResultStatus InsertDownload(Log log)
 {
 if(log.IsUser)
  {
  return glDb.UsersDownload(log);
  }
 else
  {
  return glDb.NonUsersDownload(log);
  }
 }
```

This has the advantage that you can the method signature is more expressive than a method that takes an `object` as a parameter.

Comment: From your last statement, why did you suggested a bad class design then? Btw, I haven't downvoted you.

Comment: @SomeBody How else would I use one method when there are two different model?

Comment: If you use polymorphism, type checks like above would become unnecessary. But I don't know enough about your code to see whether this is possible in your case. Anyway, the solution I posted will be able to merge your two functions into one. If it helps you, you can use it.

Comment: Ok I will look up how to use it

Comment: @SomeBody how would I use polymorphism?